# drag(move) jquery ui dialog box outside the iframe area

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have opened jquery draggable dialog box in iframe. It works fine inside the iframe but I cannot drag jquery dialog box outside the iframe. i want to drag dialog box outside the iframe. Have anybody idea how can I do this?

Below is the sample code i have used in movable.php file.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://www.jquerydemo.dailyfreecode.com/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://www.jquerydemo.dailyfreecode.com/Styles/css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
.ui-dialog
{
position:relative !important;
top:0px !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a id="hlOpenMe" href="#">Click Me to Open Dialog Box</a>
<div id="dialog" title="My Dialog Title">
<p>This is My Dialog box Description/Content</p>
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

$("#hlOpenMe").click(
function () {
$("#dialog").dialog('open');
return false;
}
);
});
</script>
</body>
```

now i have call iframe in demo.php page.

```
<iframe src="movable.php" id="name" name="test" width="50%" height="50%">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Hey man,know one answer of this question.This is important for him.

Comment: Thanx manish but i dont think anybody have answer for this question.this is way beyond of them mind.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. To your script the browser window is the iFrame from which it was called. jQuery doesn't know there is and "Outside" to the iFrame.